# Visiting two different superdomains in the same test in cypress.io

Tags: cypress

I'm currently working on the automation of a website using cypress.io and I am facing following issues:

My website has a login hosted on a different sub-domain and the whole website is served from a different domain. So, after the logging into the website, it prompts cross-origin request.

To fix that I made `{"chromeWebSecurity" : false}` in **cypress.json**. After this doing this it is not able to traverse the website past the login as it is throwing the following two errors:

> (PAGE LOAD) --page loaded-- (NEW URL) chrome-error://chromewebdata/

Comment: Take a read through here, they specifically recommend against what you're trying to do.  You can use `cy.request()` to login with a third party login provider. https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html#Visiting-external-sites

Comment: cy.request() doesn't renders the page. I first have to very specifically get the login page(different superdomain) then do the interaction with the page. After that, I will get redirected to different superdomain to check for my functionality.

Comment: They suggest using `cy.request()` to log in with a 3rd party authentication provider without using the UI.  It is a different, and better approach than selenium or other traditional UI testing frameworks.  I suggest you do some reading in the cypress docs.  I am doing the same thing in my testing.

Comment: I am not using 3rd party login. I am using the login of my own website but hosted on a different domain. After login the website is hosted on the different domain. for example Login Page--->>> **abc.xyz.com** whole website -->> **def.xyz.com**. When turning the googleWebSecurity : false it is giving (PAGE LOAD) --page loaded-- (NEW URL) chrome-error://chromewebdata/ error

Comment: Since these are different domains, best practice is to test them separately to isolate what you are actually testing.  In your tests for `def.xyz.com` you'll use `cy.request()` to send `abc.xyz.com` whatever data it needs to authenticate the user, then you are authenticated without having to load the UI for `abc.xyz.com`.  Then you will have a separate test that tests the UI login flow for `abx.xyz.com`.